# Laravel Eager Loading, filtering and limit column fields does not work

Tags: laravel-4

I want to filter my selection of columns in my channels hasmany relation as well filtering it using where method but to no avail. Any idea?

```
$data['users'] = Users::with(array('Channels' => function($q){
  $q->where('is_default','=', 1)->select(array('channel_name', 'channel_id'));
}))->get(array('id'));
```

But this works perfectly fine.

```
$data['users'] =  Users::with(array('Channels' => function($q){
 $q->where('is_default','=', 1)
}))->get(array('id'));
```

I tried putting the select method first before the where method still does not work

**EDIT:**
These are SQL queries executed which is really what I wanted however it does not fill up the relations property.

select `created_at`, `id`, `name`, `referrer` from `users` where `status` = ? limit 10 offset 0

select `channel_name`, `channel_id` from `channels` where `channels`.`user_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `is_default` = ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
$data['users'] = Users::with(array('Channels' => function($q){
    $q->select('id, channel_name', 'user_id')->where('is_default','=', 1);
}))->get();
```

If you want to select columns in `get()` then make sure you select the associated `key` for `channels` table, for example, assuming that `user_id` is the foreign key in `chennels table` so you can do it using this:

```
$data['users'] = Users::with(array('Channels' => function($q){
    $q->select('id, channel_name', 'user_id')->where('is_default','=', 1);
}))->get(array('id'));
```

If you don't select the `primary key` in the main query and `foreign key` in the sub query then `with` will not work. In both `querys/select` the related keys should be available.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, the structure goes like this the Users model has many channels. The channels table has a foreign key user_id that references the id in the users table. I have tried what you suggested, adding the user_id in the get() and it returned an sql error of missing fields. The SQL was this: select `id`, `user_id` from `users` which is really incorrect.

Comment: Check the updated answer, in both answers the `user_id` must be present in the `select` statement because 'user_id' is the foreign key.